# Putting rectangles on a square

Tags: combinatorics

I have $2020$ sticks, where the $n$-th stick has dimensions $n\times 1,\ n\in\{1,\ldots,2020\}$. I want to put my sticks on a square table so that the sticks don't overlap, but the sides of the square has to be an integer. What is the area of the smallest square that is possible?

I know that the square can have side length $2020$, because the other sticks can be laid out next to the largest, but I'm not sure if its possible to have $1010\sqrt{2}$ length side because the other sticks might not fit.

Answer (score 1):

You need at least $1010\frac 12\sqrt 2$ because if $FG=2020$ you have to add $\frac{\sqrt 2}2$ for the little triangles at the end of the $1 \times 2020$.  That still isn't enough because $FI=\frac 12$ but $IJ=1$ so the corner of the $1 \times 2019$ will stick out.  $J$ is $\frac {\sqrt 2}4$ above the top of the other square, so we can get by with $1010 \frac 34 \sqrt 2$.  The $1 \times 2018$ goes below the $1 \times 2020$, then the $1 \times 2017$ fits next to the $1 \times 2019$.  The $1 \times 2018$ hits the right and bottom of the square, so I think this is the smallest square you can manage with this approach.

[image]